# How to get the contents of a text file (stored locally in the documents directory) into an NSString?

Tags: iphone

How to retrieve the contents of a **TEXT FILE** stored locally in the documents directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text is UTF-8 encoded:

```
NSData *textFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToTextFile];
NSString *textFileString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[textFileData bytes]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this `NSString` class method (assuming the text is UTF-8):

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToTextFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

`error` should be a pointer to an `NSError` object.